# Text cutting off when exporting map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, legend, text

[image]

For some reason my labels keep cutting off; the same happens with my legend when converting to pdf or jpeg.

I am using ArcMap 10.8 and have never experienced this issued until my ArcMap was reinstalled on a new laptop.

I have attached a map - the label are suppose to read Welverdien, Utah Camp, camp b and so on, from the picture it is seen that only letters are showing and legend is also scrambled.

How can I fix this?